# Why is -1 ** 2 == -1?

Tags: python

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 25 2014, 10:19:55) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> -1 ** 2 == -1
True
```

Why is that so? I expected it to be 1.

Comment: Because it is simply math? Or do you get other results if you calculate it by hand? See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python considered that to be `-(1 ** 2) == -1`. Note that:

```
>>> (-1)**2 == -1
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations.  Powers are performed before addition or subtraction.  Thus the minus sign is only noted after squaring 1.

Comment: See Section 5.15   https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Or, to prevent you having to scroll all the way down : https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

Comment: unary minus and substraction are different.